# method return value call before function runs in program

Tags: c#, equals

I am trying to understand generic data type in C# 4.5 and I have created class check, in which simple method CompareMyValue with return type bool is comparing two values. now in my main class i create object and call this method with input parameters but I have realize during debugging, the method in main class call doesn't return correct result for bool a1 and a2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace C_Sharp_Practice_Code_01.GenericCollection
{
class check<UNKNOWNDATATYPE>
 {
    public bool CompareMyValue(UNKNOWNDATATYPE x, UNKNOWNDATATYPE y)
    {
        if(x.Equals(y))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

### main class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using C_Sharp_Practice_Code_01.GenericCollection;

namespace C_Sharp_Practice_Code_01
{
 class mainClass
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mainClass obj1 = new mainClass();

        obj1.call_GenericClass();
    }
    public void call_GenericClass()
    {
        check<int> _check = new check<int>();
        check<string> _check2 = new check<string>();

        bool a1 = _check.CompareMyValue(1, 1);
        bool a2 = _check2.CompareMyValue("xyz", "xyz");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: `a1` and `a2` should both be `true`. Are you getting different results?

Comment: Where in the program did you break the debugger? Both should resolve to true.

Comment: Also, please check naming conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx

Comment: Your question is incomplete, what are the expected results of a1 and a2? And what are your results?

Comment: I am getting false value for a2 which should be true..

Comment: Then you are either comparing different strings than you posted or you inserted a breakpoint at the line containing the second CompareMyValue call when you should have inserted it at the closing bracket right after.

Comment: this is strange i put debug mark in check class next if condition and result comes true, now even without debug check point in check class and i haven't change any code but before it wasn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The method in main class call doesn't return correct result for bool
>   a1 and a2.

Maybe you checked your boolean variable on the line **before** calling the CompareMyValue-Function?

---

I tested your code in a sample project and it worked fine for me:

```
bool a1 = _check.CompareMyValue(1, 1); 
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(a1.ToString()); // prints true
bool a2 = _check2.CompareMyValue("xyz", "xyz");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(a2.ToString()); // prints true
bool a3 = _check2.CompareMyValue("x", "y"); // another example
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(a3.ToString()); // prints false
```

Comment: i am getting false value for a2

Comment: @toxic I am getting true. ;-)

Comment: this is strange i put debug mark point in check class next to if condition where i am comparing x and y and result comes true, now even without debug check point in check class and i haven't change any code which wasn't before!!!

Comment: @toxic I assume you set the breakpoint to line 'bool a3 = ...' then the a3 is false, because it hasn't executed the method 'CompareMyValue' yet.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work...

```
class check<T>
{
    public bool CompareMyValue(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x.Equals(y))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then Tested it with

```
check<int> intChecker = new check<int>();
Console.WriteLine(intChecker.CompareMyValue(4, 5).ToString());
Console.ReadKey();

check<string> strChecker = new check<string>();
Console.WriteLine(strChecker.CompareMyValue("The test", "The test").ToString());
Console.ReadKey();

check<decimal> decChecker = new check<decimal>();
Console.WriteLine(decChecker.CompareMyValue(1.23456m, 1.23456m).ToString());
Console.ReadKey();

check<DateTime> dateChecker = new check<DateTime>();
Console.WriteLine(dateChecker.CompareMyValue(new DateTime(2013, 12, 25), new DateTime(2013, 12, 24)).ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```